# diff files but with some text ignored in comparisons

Tags: shell, diff

I have two files:

file1.txt:

```
boring stuff
interesting value = 123  !ts:yesterday
interesting value = 456  !ts:yesterday
boring stuff
```

file2.txt:

```
boring stuff
interesting value = 123  !ts:today
interesting value = 789  !ts:today
boring stuff
```

Now, `diff -u file1.txt file2.txt` will highlight both `interesting value` lines because the text after `!ts:` has changed.  Not what I want.  I only want to see that the second `interesting value` has changed, without being informed that the first one stayed the same but has a different comment after it.

So I can do this:

```
diff -u <(sed -e 's/\!ts:.*$//' file1.txt) <(sed -e 's/\!ts:.*$//' file2.txt)
```

```
    @@ -1,4 +1,4 @@
     boring stuff
     interesting value = 123  
    -interesting value = 456  
    +interesting value = 789  
     boring stuff
```

great!

But now I can't see the filtered-out text in the output.  I need to put the filtered-out context back in after the filtered comparison is performed, so I understand the context of the change in the diff, but without the context itself being considered a mismatch.

Is there any way to achieve this?  The only filter switch I could find, `-I`, removes the matching lines entirely.

Comment: which comment should the 123 line display? original or changed?

Comment: The `-` and `+` is a *from* and *to* where the lines before the change and immediately after are provide as context. Are you wanting to cut down the context shown or the `-`?

Answer (score 1):

**filterdiff.awk** :

```
# print lines saved up to this point
function emit() {
    for (i=1; i<=n; i++)
        if (i in lines)
            print lines[i]
}

/^@@/ {
    emit()

    # reset state
    split(_,lookup)
    n = split(_,lines)

    # no longer in diff header section
    filtering = 1
}

filtering {
    if (i = index($0,"!ts:")) {
        want = substr($0, 2, i-2)

        if (/^[-]/) {
            # save state
            lookup[want] = n+1
        }
        else if (/^[+]/ && i = lookup[want]) {
            # line exists in old and new - edit it

            # keep old or new version?
            if (keep_new) lines[i] = $0

            sub(/^./, " ", lines[i])
            next
        }
    }
}

# save lines to print later
{ lines[++n] = $0 }

END { emit() }
```

```
$ diff -u old new | awk -f filterdiff.awk
--- file1.txt   2023-11-04 02:01:45.062527075 +0000
+++ file2.txt   2023-11-04 02:01:48.306560296 +0000
@@ -1,4 +1,4 @@
 boring stuff
 interesting value = 123  !ts:yesterday
-interesting value = 456  !ts:yesterday
+interesting value = 789  !ts:today
 boring stuff
$
```

```
$ diff -u old new | awk -f filterdiff.awk keep_new=1
--- file1.txt   2023-11-04 02:01:45.062527075 +0000
+++ file2.txt   2023-11-04 02:01:48.306560296 +0000
@@ -1,4 +1,4 @@
 boring stuff
 interesting value = 123  !ts:today
-interesting value = 456  !ts:yesterday
+interesting value = 789  !ts:today
 boring stuff
```

---

The code above requires the `-` and `+` lines to both appear in the same `@@` block.

Here is a variation that may replace across blocks. It probably requires the "interesting" data to be unique.

**filterdiff2.awk** :

```
{ lines[NR] = $0 }

i = index($0, "!ts:") {
    q = substr($0, 2, i-2)
    if (/^[-]/) old[q] = NR
    if (/^[+]/) new[q] = NR
}

END {
    for (q in old)
        if (q in new) {
            if (keep_new)
                lines[ old[q] ] = lines[ new[q] ]
            sub(/^[-+]/, " ", lines[ old[q] ])
            delete lines[ new[q] ]
        }
    for (i=1; i<=NR; i++)
        if (i in lines)
            print lines[i]
}
```

Comment: this might fail in some corner cases. eg. if there are multiple copies of old and new in an @@ block

Comment: Worthy answer. Your crystal-ball is working much better than mine tonight `:)`